# Unicode range for Vietnamese

Tags: unicode, fonts, subset, webfonts

The Google Fonts' Source Sans Pro implementation contains a Vietnamese subsetting, however, it contains various missing glyphs, as discussed in [Issue #90](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-sans-pro/issues/90) of the Source Sans Pro github account, but closed by the maintainers.

The problem is visible in the following snippet.

```css
/*
 Fall back to serif so the 
 missing glyphs are more
 easily visible
*/
body {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", serif;
  font-size: 25px;
}
p {
  margin: .1em 0 1em;
}
small {
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #999;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.w200 { font-weight: 200; }
.w300 { font-weight: 300; }
.w400 { font-weight: 400; }
.w600 { font-weight: 600; }
.w700 { font-weight: 700; }
.w900 { font-weight: 900; }
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:200,300,400,600,700,900&amp;subset=vietnamese" media="all">

<small>Source Sans Pro Vietnamese 200</small>
<p class="w200">Đánh giá nhanh + khảo sát riêng: Hướng dẫn bắt đầu nhanh.  Giờ đây, các nhà nghỉ có thể thu thập đánh giá TripAdvisor và phản hồi riêng của khách bằng một email đơn giản. Sau đây là cách thực hiện. Bắt đầu với Đánh giá nhanh + khảo sát riêng. Nhấp vào đây. Giờ đây, các nhà nghỉ có thể thu thập đánh giá TripAdvisor và phản hồi riêng của khách bằng một email đơn giản. Đánh giá nhanh + khảo sát riêng là gì? Bước 2: Chọn câu hỏi. Bước 3: Đăng khảo sát. Bước 4: Xem kết quả. Tùy chỉnh Khảo sát riêng của quý vị ngay.</p>

<small>Source Sans Pro Vietnamese 300</small>
<p class="w300">Đánh giá nhanh + khảo sát riêng: Hướng dẫn bắt đầu nhanh.  Giờ đây, các nhà nghỉ có thể thu thập đánh giá TripAdvisor và phản hồi riêng của khách bằng một email đơn giản. Sau đây là cách thực hiện. Bắt đầu với Đánh giá nhanh + khảo sát riêng. Nhấp vào đây. Giờ đây, các nhà nghỉ có thể thu thập đánh giá TripAdvisor và phản hồi riêng của khách bằng một email đơn giản. Đánh giá nhanh + khảo sát riêng là gì? Bước 2: Chọn câu hỏi. Bước 3: Đăng khảo sát. Bước 4: Xem kết quả. Tùy chỉnh Khảo sát riêng của quý vị ngay.</p>
 
<small>Source Sans Pro Vietnamese 400</small>
<p class="w400">Đánh giá nhanh + khảo sát riêng: Hướng dẫn bắt đầu nhanh.  Giờ đây, các nhà nghỉ có thể thu thập đánh giá TripAdvisor và phản hồi riêng của khách bằng một email đơn giản. Sau đây là cách thực hiện. Bắt đầu với Đánh giá nhanh + khảo sát riêng. Nhấp vào đây. Giờ đây, các nhà nghỉ có thể thu thập đánh giá TripAdvisor và phản hồi riêng của khách bằng một email đơn giản. Đánh giá nhanh + khảo sát riêng là gì? Bước 2: Chọn câu hỏi. Bước 3: Đăng khảo sát. Bước 4: Xem kết quả. Tùy chỉnh Khảo sát riêng của quý vị ngay.</p>
  
<small>Source Sans Pro Vietnamese 600</small>
<p class="w600">Đánh giá nhanh + khảo sát riêng: Hướng dẫn bắt đầu nhanh.  Giờ đây, các nhà nghỉ có thể thu thập đánh giá TripAdvisor và phản hồi riêng của khách bằng một email đơn giản. Sau đây là cách thực hiện. Bắt đầu với Đánh giá nhanh + khảo sát riêng. Nhấp vào đây. Giờ đây, các nhà nghỉ có thể thu thập đánh giá TripAdvisor và phản hồi riêng của khách bằng một email đơn giản. Đánh giá nhanh + khảo sát riêng là gì? Bước 2: Chọn câu hỏi. Bước 3: Đăng khảo sát. Bước 4: Xem kết quả. Tùy chỉnh Khảo sát riêng của quý vị ngay.</p>
  
<small>Source Sans Pro Vietnamese 700</small>
<p class="w700">Đánh giá nhanh + khảo sát riêng: Hướng dẫn bắt đầu nhanh.  Giờ đây, các nhà nghỉ có thể thu thập đánh giá TripAdvisor và phản hồi riêng của khách bằng một email đơn giản. Sau đây là cách thực hiện. Bắt đầu với Đánh giá nhanh + khảo sát riêng. Nhấp vào đây. Giờ đây, các nhà nghỉ có thể thu thập đánh giá TripAdvisor và phản hồi riêng của khách bằng một email đơn giản. Đánh giá nhanh + khảo sát riêng là gì? Bước 2: Chọn câu hỏi. Bước 3: Đăng khảo sát. Bước 4: Xem kết quả. Tùy chỉnh Khảo sát riêng của quý vị ngay.</p>

<small>Source Sans Pro Vietnamese 900</small>
<p class="w900">Đánh giá nhanh + khảo sát riêng: Hướng dẫn bắt đầu nhanh.  Giờ đây, các nhà nghỉ có thể thu thập đánh giá TripAdvisor và phản hồi riêng của khách bằng một email đơn giản. Sau đây là cách thực hiện. Bắt đầu với Đánh giá nhanh + khảo sát riêng. Nhấp vào đây. Giờ đây, các nhà nghỉ có thể thu thập đánh giá TripAdvisor và phản hồi riêng của khách bằng một email đơn giản. Đánh giá nhanh + khảo sát riêng là gì? Bước 2: Chọn câu hỏi. Bước 3: Đăng khảo sát. Bước 4: Xem kết quả. Tùy chỉnh Khảo sát riêng của quý vị ngay.</p>
```

I'd like to create and host my own version of Source Sans Pro, using a Vietnamese subsetting because SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf is well over 200K.  However, neither [fontie](https://fontie.flowyapps.com/home) nor [FontSquirrel](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) provide a *one-click* way to choose the Vietnamese subsetting.

**What are the unicode ranges I would need to specify in the FontSquirrel Advanced UI to produce a functioning Vietnamese webfont?**

Is there a definitive list somewhere that can be used for reference?

Comment: Did you fix the problem in your snippet? If so, do you remember what your solution was?

Comment: Is it just that source sans pro just not have the required characters in the required font weights?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [vietunicode project](http://vietunicode.sourceforge.net) has [a list of characters that it claims is the "complete set"](http://vietunicode.sourceforge.net/charset/vietalphabet.html):

> aAàÀảẢãÃáÁạẠăĂằẰẳẲẵẴắẮặẶâÂầẦẩẨẫẪấẤậẬbBcCdDđĐeEèÈẻẺẽẼéÉẹẸêÊềỀểỂễỄếẾệỆ
>   fFgGhHiIìÌỉỈĩĨíÍịỊjJkKlLmMnNoOòÒỏỎõÕóÓọỌôÔồỒổỔỗỖốỐộỘơƠờỜởỞỡỠớỚợỢpPqQrRsStTu
>   UùÙủỦũŨúÚụỤưƯừỪửỬữỮứỨựỰvVwWxXyYỳỲỷỶỹỸýÝỵỴzZ

In numeric/Unicode code point terms, that is:

```
U+0041-U+005A, U+0061-U+007A, U+00C0-U+00C3, U+00C8-U+00CA,
U+00CC-U+00CD, U+00D2-U+00D5, U+00D9-U+00DA, U+00DD, 
U+00E0-U+00E3, U+00E8-U+00EA, U+00EC-U+00ED, U+00F2-U+00F5,
U+00F9-U+00FA, U+00FD, U+0102-U+0103, U+0110-U+0111,
U+0128-U+0129, U+0168-U+0169, U+01A0-U+01A1, U+01AF-U+01B0,
U+1EA0-U+1EF9
```

A complete font should probably include the full Basic Latin `U+0020-U+007E` and Latin-1 `U+00A0-U+00FF` for non-Vietnamese-specific symbols and text that are likely to appear. I also note that the list does not appear to contain `U+20AB` (DONG SIGN) or `U+20AC` (EURO SIGN), which I'd include if present in the original fonts, as these may be useful/necessary for dealing with currencies.

---

**Update:**

[This blog post on int3ractive.com](http://blog.int3ractive.com/2010/06/optimal-unicode-range-for-vietnamese.html) points out that Vietnamese may also be written using additional "composite" characters where a vowel character is followed by a diacritic *ghost* character to create what looks like a single character on the page, requiring the following range if your font supports it:

```
U+02C6-U+0323
```

The complete "optimal" set according to Int3ractive:

```
U+0020-U+002F, U+0030-U+0039, U+003A-U+0040, U+0041-U+005A,
U+005B-U+0060, U+0061-U+007A, U+007B-U+007E, U+00C0-U+00C3,
U+00C8-U+00CA, U+00CC-U+00CD, U+00D0, U+00D2-U+00D5, 
U+00D9-U+00DA, U+00DD, U+00E0-U+00E3, U+00E8-U+00EA, 
U+00EC-U+00ED, U+00F2-U+00F5, U+00F9-U+00FA, U+00FD,
U+0102-U+0103, U+0110-U+0111, U+0128-U+0129, U+0168-U+0169,
U+01A0-U+01B0, U+1EA0-U+1EF9, U+02C6-U+0323
```

Comment: funny, i saw that website, but what with the wall of text, I couldnt find a listing of ranges. Where exactly did you see that?

Comment: I linked to the exact page in my answer: http://vietunicode.sourceforge.net/charset/vietalphabet.html . The content is near the bottom of that page, and is also reproduced in my answer, along with code points (which I could not readily locate on that site).

Comment: To clarify: I derived the code points by analyzing the text listing.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification. I'm hoping for an actual official list of unicode codepoints and ranges, not a derived list calculated from inspecting a list of characters.

Comment: I just found this: https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Vietnamese_Standard_Code_for_Information_Interchange not sure how official it is.

Comment: I think I'm stumbling upon understanding my problem more clearly because it seems like some of the glyphs are composed of a glyph plus a separate diacritic, composed into a single character.  eg `ả` versus `ả`

Comment: Well the list of characters is not exactly "official" anyway. Do you mistrust my analysis? If so, why? There are a number of tools available to "convert" from text to code points that will readily corroborate (it is not exactly rocket science).

Comment: I don't distrust, but I dont think it is complete. You've forgotten the diacritics  which are required to create `ả`  , namely U+0061 and U+0309 composed together.

Comment: This site contains a virtual keyboard that includes some diacritics at the bottom.  https://r12a.github.io/pickers/vietnamese/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113578/discussion-between-djangodude-and-jameswilson).